# problema con consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente tabla mysql:

```
|ID|LOT_NUMBER|STATE  |
|--| -------- | ----- |
| 1|  1       |    0  |
| 2|  1       |    0  |
| 3|  2       |    1  |
| 4|  2       |    0  |
| 5|  3       |    1  |
| 6|  3       |    1  |
| 7|  4       |    0  |
| 8|  4       |    0  |
```

Necesito una consulta mysql que obtenga solo los registros cuyo estado es = 0 pero solo si todos los registros con el mismo número de lote tienen el estado 0, es decir, esto es lo que la consulta debería arrojarme:

```
|LOT_NUMBER|TOTAL_FILES|
| -------- | --------- |
|  1       |    2      |
|  4       |    2      |
```

espero haberme hecho entender, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así diría yo...

```
SELECT LOT_NUMBER, COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL_FILES
FROM table_name
WHERE STATE = 0 AND LOT_NUMBER NOT IN (
    SELECT LOT_NUMBER
    FROM table_name
    WHERE STATE > 0
)
GROUP BY LOT_NUMBER
```

Buena suerte!

Comment: gracias man, me soluciono el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esta consulta.

```
select x.LOT_NUMBER, x.TOTAL_FILES
from (SELECT LOT_NUMBER, COUNT(*) as  TOTAL_FILES from table1 WHERE STATE = 0 GROUP by LOT_NUMBER) as x
WHERE x.TOTAL_FILES > 1;
```

En el apartado de from se crea una tabla derivada que contiene los campos que deseas consultar, se hace un conteo con los resultado que se establece en el where en este caso que `STATE = 0` y se agrupan por `LOT_NUMBER`.